# SignalR - How to call server function with parameter from client using hubproxy

Tags: signalr

I have my signalr running on a separate domain. We will have multiple applications using it to send and receive messages. I created the connection and hub proxy using the following code

```
connection = $.hubConnection("https://someurl.com", { useDefaultPath: false });
            chatHub = connection.createHubProxy('chatHub');
```

I can get messages from the server sent to the client using the following code which works fine

```
chatHub.on('receiveEntityMessage', function (chatMessage) {
                if (chatMessage) {
                    console.log(chatMessage.Message);
                }
            });
```

Now I dont know how to call server functions with parameters from the client. Can anybody please help me with this?

Comment: Show your hub and how you invoke the server method.

Answer (score 1):

```
chatHub.invoke("MethodName", param1, param2, param3).done(function(result) {
   console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: I had tried that already. I just get an error - Error: There was an error invoking Hub method...
I have kept the method names lower case to ensure no issues. Also when I look at the auto generated hubs file under the signalr folder, I cannot see my methods in it. Should my methods be in it.

Comment: I can now see the method in the autogenerated hubs file but still get the same error.

Comment: There must be another problem then, are you providing the correct amount of parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Since i'm not sure what is the language of your server side, i am going to provide a C# example.

## C# Hub method example:

```
public class chatHub: Hub {

    public void YourHubMehotd(int firstParam, string secondParam){

        //The action of your method

    }

}
```

## JS client side:

You can call your hub method like this:

{*The variable with the hub connection*}.server.{*the method you want to call*}( {*the parameters*} )

### Example:

```
chatHub.server.YourHubMehotd(1,"Example");
```

**I recomend to create a js function to call the hub method.**

```
function callMyHubMethod(firstParam, secondParam){

    chatHub.server.YourHubMehotd(firstParam, secondParam);

}
```